# Better coding of a jquery hover

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup, jquery-hover

I have a link`('#login_display')` that slides down a sub-menu '('.box_login')` on click. What I would like is when someone mouseout of the link OR the sub-menu, the sub-menu slides back up.

This code is working, but is there a better way to do it? Because when the mouse leave the submenu('.box_login') to go on the link('#login_display') it *lags* a little bit cause the link opens the sub-menu('.box_login') and the mouse-out close it...

Thanks

here is the script:

```
$('#login_display').hover(function() {
    $('.box_login').slideDown('normal');
}, function() {});

$('.box_login').hover(function() {}, function() {
    $('.box_login').slideUp('normal');
});
```

Comment: Can you show the markup? That would help answer you better.

Comment: Can you post your HTML to have the whole picture of it?

Comment: Your code will not hide `box_login` if you just move out of `login_display`, how is working for you?

Comment: website is : www.entendu.info

link is "connexion"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your site, this is what will work best for you. Try this.

```
$('#login_display').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('mouseovertimer'));
    clearTimeout($('.box_login').data('mouseovertimer'));
    $('.box_login').slideDown('normal');
}, function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('mouseovertimer', setTimeout(function(){
         $('.box_login').slideUp('normal');
    }, 100));
});

$('.box_login').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout($('#login_display').data('mouseovertimer'));
}, function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('mouseovertimer', setTimeout(function(){
         $this.slideUp('normal');
    }, 100));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/ezC7a/1/)**

Comment: Damn this is exactly what I was looking for !
If one day you got 5 mintues to explain me a little bit about how it works I would be happy to learn.

Comment: The solution is simple. I have a timeout on mouseout of link as well as box. Within that time if you hover on any of those just clear the timeout so that the box does not slide up. Added the demo too take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I would place your link and your slide down div in a container. Then use the mouseleave event of the container to slide back up.

http://jsfiddle.net/Whrec/1

```
<a class="login" id="login_display">Link</a><br/>
<div class="box_login login">blah</div>
```

```
$('#login_display').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.box_login').slideDown('normal');
});

$('.box_login, #login_display').mouseleave(function(e) {
    console.log(e.toElement);
    if (!$(e.toElement).hasClass('login'))
        $('.box_login').slideUp('normal');
});
```

Comment: problem is the div can't be together
first div is on my menu bar and th eother is on my sidebar

Comment: website is : www.entendu.info

link is "connexion"

Comment: If elements aren't next to eachother... how in the world are you supposed to put the monitor over the slidedown menu without triggering the an event leaving the link? `What I would like is when someone mouseout of the link OR the sub-menu, the sub-menu slides back up`

Comment: Ahh, I see. thanks for the link. will need to think about this.

Comment: Try this, add a class `login` to the two elements. Then check the `toElement` property of the event object to make sure you are exiting to somewhere else on the page. http://jsfiddle.net/Whrec/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simplify by using just the `mouseenter` and `mouseout` events. Also cache `$('.box_login')`. Then use `$(this)` instead of repeating `$('.box_login')` and finally remove `'normal'` since it's the default speed. Your performance will improve a little bit, but I don't think there's a whole lot you can do aside from this. Posting your html might help to get more performance improvements.

```
var $boxLogin = $('.box_login'); // Cache for speed

$('#login_display').mouseenter(function(){ 
    $boxLogin.slideDown();
});

$boxLogin.mouseout(function(){ 
   $(this).slideUp();
});
```